# How do I set the Id in the MenuItems to use in REPL?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using UiTests/ REPL, to do some tests. I need to use menuItem id, to click (Tap command in REPL) in a menuItem.

The Menuitem, is defined in the XML file with android:id="@+id/menu_settings", title and local:showAsAction="never", and appear in the "overflowButton". When I do that, in REPl, using the command "tree", the menuItem id is "title".

If I define the MenuItem in the XML file with android:id="@+id/menu_settings", title and local:showAsAction="always", in REPl, using the command "tree", the menuItem id is "menu_settings".

Seems that MenuItems that appear inside overflowbutton, have always the id "title".
If this is normal, i can't use the id do tap the menuItem.

Thanks in advance for the help,